# Rotate a line by a given angle

Tags: math, geometry, netlogo

Given the coefficients of a line A , B and C.

```
Ax + By + C = 0
```

I wish to rotate the line by angle say **x** in clockwise or ant-clockwise direction. How can I achieve this so that I get new coefficients then?(In NetLogo)

EDIT:
Sorry consider point as x_0 and y_0

Comment: You must rotate the line about some point. What is this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line equation

```
x * A + y * B + C = 0
```

may be presented in [normal form](http://schooltutoring.com/help/equation-of-a-line-normal-form/) as

```
x * Cos(Theta) + y * Sin(Theta) - p = 0
```

where

`Theta = ArcTan(B/A)`
- angle between OX axis and normal form coordinate origin to line

`p = -C/Sqrt(A^2 + B^2)` -
distance from origin to the line (normal length).

If you want to rotate the line relative to coordinate origin (0,0) by angle Alpha, just make new equation (note the same p value):
    Beta = Theta + Alpha

```
x * Cos(Beta) + y * Sin(Beta) - p = 0
```

If you want to rotate the line about arbitrary point (x0, y0):
normal distance from this point to the line was

```
d = x0 * Cos(Theta) + y0 * Sin(Theta) - p
```

new equation will

```
x * Cos(Beta) + y * Sin(Beta) - pnew = 0
```

and to preserve normal distance:

```
d = x0 * Cos(Beta) + y0 * Sin(Beta) - pnew
```

so

```
pnew = p + x0 * (Cos(Beta)-Cos(Theta)) + y0 * (Sin(Beta)-Sin(Theta))
```